# How to Organize Code in a Resource Management Phaser Typescript Project?

Tags: typescript, phaser-framework

I'm making a type of resource-management type game and I need some sort of "collection manager" in between my states and objects. I'm using Typescript.

Let's say for example that the game is about raising cats. In one state, the player can skip forward one year. When this happens I want to go through the collection of cats and select pairs to become parents of new cats. In another state the player can feed 10 cats (changing their hunger values). So in two different states, I need to update this collection of cats.

I had this code inside each state and the collection of cats was passed around through localStorage (or sometimes the Phaser Cache). So the code has become quite messy.

So I want to create an abstraction layer between the states and this collection of objects. This something would be responsible for updating the cats, creating new ones, and returning subsets of cats based on passed criteria. I would like this something to be a static layer so that I don't have to pass it between states. I would love to be able to simply call functions like:

```
catManager.generateNewCats(10);
catManager.getCats({minAge:2, maxAge:5});
catManager.incrementAges();
```

How would you go about organizing this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one potential solution:

```
/** Creates a Guid (UUID v4) */
function createId(): string {
    return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
        var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8);
        return v.toString(16);
    });
}


class Cat {
    id: string;
    constructor() {
        this.id = createId();
    }
}
class Manager {
    cats: {}
    getNew(howMany: number): Cat[] {
        const result: Cat[] = [];
        for (let index = 0; index < howMany; index++) {
            const cat = new Cat();
            this.cats[cat.id] = cat;
        }
        return result;
    }

}

export const manager = new Manager();
```

You can always identify a `cat` by its Id. You can extend the manager to buffer into places like local storage if you want.